# Mircrosoft SQl Database Large Import Error: 0xc02020a1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to import a large csv file into Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio through the 'Import and Export" Wizard.
[Data in Question, it's the "Parcels - Comma-Separated Values" csv file](https://www.denvergov.org/opendata/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-parcels)

When I try to Import it just as is these are the errors given

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "LEGAL_DESC" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - parcels_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[LEGAL_DESC]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - parcels_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[LEGAL_DESC]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\tobyr\OneDrive\Desktop\RealEstate\Data\parcels.csv" on data row 13.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - parcels_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I tried cleaning it up, replacing out the 'None' with just spaces (maybe SQL manger doesn't know 'none'= 'NULL'), using the suggested types, increasing 'headers rows to skip', changing the 'header rows delimiter' to comma. These are the results after just cleaning it up as described above (It's giving me all checkmarks during the review tab:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "SITUS_ADDR_NBR_SUFFIX" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Source - denParcels4_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[SITUS_ADDR_NBR_SUFFIX]" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Source - denParcels4_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[SITUS_ADDR_NBR_SUFFIX]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\tobyr\OneDrive\Desktop\RealEstate\Data\denParcels4.csv" on data row 2.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - denParcels4_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I have also tried setting it to ignore all error but it's just creating an empty table. And creating and empty table and using the 'BULK INSERT' query, but nothing has worked.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here? It is pretty clear about what the problem is: *"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."* Ensure that there is no truncation and/or no loss of data.

Comment: _maybe SQL manger doesn't know 'none'= 'NULL'_ No it doesn't. And NULL is not the same as 'NULL' - the latter is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to

1. remove constraints from the target table
2. set string columns sizes to a larger size
3. calibrate the import process to use text qualifier on strings (")

Probably not critical - but a quick review of record two in file https://www.denvergov.org/media/gis/DataCatalog/parcels/csv/parcels.csv has an empty value in the first column - SCHEDNUM - perhaps the target table has "not null" constraint

I believe the other errors are related to perhaps non use of text qualifiers- some records have strings wrapped in quotes

If you are tied to the target table maintaining constraints - then long process suggestion ahead - see below

THanks

In this circumstance I would port the file to a new [staging] table that does not have any constraints (e.g. not null).  I would also use a text qualifier when importing the data into the fresh table. To avoid all reasonable doubt - set string columns on the [staging] table to a reasonable size - nvarchar (255)

I'd suggest using bcp for the quick fire a file into a temporary [staging] table as it does not require much configuration to lift and shift a text file straight to table - as long as there are the same number of columns in the table as there are delimited values in the file record

bcp also provides facility to progress even if there are errors - default allow 10 errors and skip.

Once all loaded into [staging] table - create an identical table structure as the target - just with no rows.
Then build a merge statement to sweep "good" records from staging table and insert into the target table and use the capability of merge statement to load failed records into a failures table (or perform a not exists)